# Precedence of Loaders vs BroadcastReceivers started on the main thread

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-loadermanager, android-loader

Consider the following sequence of events :

1. A `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the `onResume` method of an `Activity` (without a handler).
2. A `CursorLoader` is  started by calling the `restartLoader` method as the next immediate statement in `onResume` (`restartLoader` is called on the *main* thread itself)

My observations is that `onLoadFinished` method always gets called before the first call to `onReceive`. That is, the `CursorLoader` takes precedence over the `BroadcastReciever`. Moreover, the `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver` does not get called until the `onLoadFinished` method completes.

Assuming that  :

1. There is a foreground service already running in the background that is publishing messages for my `BroadcastReciever` even before the app is launched for the first time **AND**
2. Considering that the `BroadcastReciever` is registered before the `CursorLoader` is started, shouldn't the `onReceive` method get triggered immediately considering there are already messages available for the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Since this is not the case, I am lead to believe that the `CursorLoader` takes precedence over a `BroadcastReceiver` when started on the main thread of an activity. However, I can't seem to find any documentaiton for this.

How can I ensure that my `BroadcastReceiver` gets precedence over the `CursorLoader`? This behavior is important because I want my `Activity` to be initialized with some information that is being broadcasted by the foreground service even if the app is being launched newly (i.e onCreate being called on the `ACtivity`). The `CursorLoader` needs this information to create the `Uri` to be used for fetching the relevant data and showing it on the UI. Since the `CursorLoader` runs before the `BroadcastReciever`, it constructs a `Uri` without this information and subsequently fetches stale data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Loaders are deprecated and would highly suggest refactoring to use ViewModel. You can also use Live Data in Conjunction.

Link to ViewModel [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)
Link to Live Data [LiveData Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. As I understand, loaders are deprecated from API level 28 onwards. I believe refactoring an entire app for a small percentage of devices that support API level 28 is something that can be deferred for a couple of years. That said, sill using the ViewModel component along with LiveData solve my problem described in the question?

Comment: This post on stack may help : [Dataflow between Android BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider, and Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662344/dataflow-between-android-broadcastreceiver-contentprovider-and-activity)

Comment: Thanks for the help once again; however, I don't want to start my `Activity` from a `BroadcastReciever`. My activity is the one that registers the `BroadcastReciever` and my requirement is that the `onReceive` method of this `BroadcastReciever` runs before the `CursorLoader`. Does that make sense?